# Is there any "SpringBoot way" so i can start different Main Classes Applications from the same Jar File?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, launcher, mainclass

I Mean, that i DON´T want to create a Centralizer Main Class and pass parameter to it, so it can choose and start the @SpringBoot class for me...

In the other hand, I do not consider starting the classes with "java -cp  ". This way it is not SpringBoot which starts the classes, but you are forcing manually the class to be started.

What i am looking for is an elegant built-in "Spring Way" to start my diferent  @SpringBoot classes from command line. Any Special Launcher? Something in the App properties files?

What i realize is a Launcher which may receive "spring.application.name" for instance by command line and so use that to choose the desired @SpringBoot class.

Comment: Use [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not put multiple Main Classes in the Manifest.

What you can do is put the JAR in the classpath and call the main class

`java -jar yourLib.jar` will start the Main Class from manifest

`java -cp youLib.jar your.1st.main.Class`

`java -cp youLib.jar your.2nd.main.Class`